# Changing shopify dropdown menu to select a certain preview image

Tags: html, ruby, image, shopify, edit

I was just wondering if there is any way to select a shopify preview image, so that when it is clicked, it selects the product from the dropdown menu.  It can all be set individually, however I need it site wide.

I've attached an image to show what I mean. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URM8H.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: It's definitely possible. You could assign each image to its image in the product dashboard and change the option via JavaScript then. How proficient are you with JS?

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what I was thinking.  Was looking for a way to do it all without having to individually select the products.